# How to overpass "Confirm Form Resubmission" in PHP

Tags: php, forms, submit

I have 3 pages.

-page1.php sends data through a form with post action

-page2.php recieves data from page1.php. In page2.php there is a link to   page3.php

-page3.php does some staff.

When i click to go back from page3 to page2 occures

> Confirm Form Resubmission
>
> ERR_CACHE_MISS

I understand the reason of this behaviour. When I take data from page1 to page2 I store some of them in session so i don't need always to use submit. How can i check if submit was done in order to continue normally if no submit was used?

Here is some code of page2:

```
<?php
if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
    session_start();
}

global $dbcnx;

if (isset($_POST['submit']))//if i submit i store in session
{
    $_SESSION['team_name'] = $_POST['teams'];
    echo $_SESSION['team_name'];
}

else //do nothing
{}

//conitnue code normally
.
.
.
```

That was my last try. Any response will be helpfull. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual way to prevent that is to redirect to a page with no post data, click the link to see more info on [How to make a redirect in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/768431/how-to-make-a-redirect-in-php)

Comment: Actually yes! The answer is really simple. Thanks for the quick response!

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that you should redirect to a specific page using php.that is done with `header()`.
this should be a help:

```
header("Location: http://www.something.com/any/thing.php")   //the page can be anything
```

Of course, if you're using xampp or wamp or whatever server, use it this way:

```
header("Location: http://localhost/any/thing.php")   //the page can be anything
```